# Struts2 type conversion of a flattened JSON object in a query string

Tags: java, ajax, json, struts2, kendo-ui

EDIT: Changed question title and content. Upon reading the [JSON plugin guide](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/json-plugin.html) I realize the plugin might be expecting a JSON string instead of this query map, in which case I normally go with GSON instead. I guess the question becomes: how can Struts2 handle type conversion of a query string like this: `sort[0][field]=status&sort[0][dir]=asc`

---

I am using Kendo UI grid to interface with my Struts2 backend. The AJAX request being sent to the server follows the following format (GET query string):

```
take=5&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=5&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=status&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc
```

or (non-escaped):

```
take=5&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=5&sort[0][field]=status&sort[0][dir]=asc
```

Basically, Kendo UI grid is sending a flattened JSON object to the server. So I create a sort model object like so to take the input:

```
public class SortModel {
    private String field;
    private String dir;
}
```

and include this in my Struts2 action as a variable to be populated:

```
private SortModel[] sort;
```

However, this never gets populated by Struts2 when the AJAX request comes in. I also tried to add the JSON interceptor, but I think I misunderstood its deserialization process, as explained in the edit.

Anyway, has anyone managed to Struts2 type conversion working using the above query string or similar: `sort[0][field]=status&sort[0][dir]=asc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sort[0][field]=status&sort[0][dir]=asc

The above is not proper JSON, strings should be quoted. With that done the following will work.

In which case a field (or json parameter) in the form `name[i]['s']` which has a value of String and where i is an integer and s is any string would be backed by:

```
private List<Map<String, String>> name = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

//getter AND setter required
```

PS: With Struts2 you can index into lists of lists of lists... without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.

It turns out that vanilla Struts2 doesn't accept query strings in the format `obj[idx][property]` (feel free to correct me on this). I was expecting it to convert the query string to an array of that specific object.

What Struts2 does accept is the format `obj[idx].property` which it will correctly convert to `private Object[] obj`.

So I guess the possible solutions to this would be:

1. JSON.stringify(jsonObj) before passing it to the query string, a la `&jsonData=[{property:'value'}]` - which in this case, I can't do since Kendo UI grid doesn't seem to have an interceptor-like event to let me change the query parameters. Or,
2. Implement a custom type converter that handles this particular format. Or,
3. Intercept the AJAX request before it is being sent to the server and re-format the query string, using jQuery.ajaxSend e.g.

   ```
   $(body).ajaxSend(function(event, req, settings){
       console.log(settings.url); //contains the url string to replace
       settings.url = settings.url.replace(some_regex, 'correct format');
   });
   ```

Comment: Quaternion's answer clarifies my questions about accepted formats. `param[0][string]` is not valid, but `param[0]['string']` is valid JSON and convertible by Struts2.